# How can I monitoring an installer?

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, files, sudo, monitoring

I would like to install a 3rd party software on my system. Unfortunately, it is not open source, and it is comes with it's own custom installer. It want me to enter my sudo password to install the program. However, I'd like to make sure that it will not install any malicious files, so I would like to use a "monitoring" program, which will display all installed files by this installer.

This monitoring program is exist somewhere?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://ostechnix.com/monitor-file-changes-using-fswatch-linux/) or [this](https://www.ihaveapc.com/2011/11/how-to-monitor-file-system-changes-in-linux-in-real-time/)? Just use a search engine 'linux monitor file system for changes' or similar.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `installwatch` (`sudo apt install checkinstall`). It uses a preloaded library to intercept, log, and complete system calls.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a TimeShift backup before and after the install to see what system files have changed. Also it gives you a change to revert back if something fails.